# Is $\mathbb{R}^2$ with product defined like $(x, y)\cdot(a, b)=(ax, by)$, and usual addition, a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

It satisfies the definition of field. The multiplicative identity can be $(1,1)$. So, is it a field this way too (other than the obvious complex number way)?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Have you verified the other requirements for being a field? You should read something about formatting math with MathJax/LaTeX here, the help center has a couple of links you can start with.

Comment: Have you thought about inverses?

Answer (score 2):

Well! clearly not because by definition every non-zero element should be invertible but any element of the forms $(x,0)$ or $(0,y)$ are not invertible clearly.
I hope this works.

Answer (score 1):

$(1,0) \cdot (0,1)=(0,0)$ so you have zero divisors.  It’s not even an integral domain.